# Using variables in a node.js mysql-node query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am running a mysql query with WHERE, I would like to include my input prompt variable, input how would I go about doing so? my current query is like so,

```
var connect = connection.query('SELECT url FROM Sonic_url WHERE name='   
 + input //<where I'm confused
, function(err, rows, fields) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just include it the way you did, but that will give you an unescaped query which is open to sql - injection. To prevent you from this, you can use `mysql.format`

```
var sql = mysql.format("SELECT url FROM Sonic_url WHERE name=?", [input]);
var connection = connection.query(sql, function(err,rows,fields) {});
```

Comment: Thank you! also, any good method of hiding mysql logins in a script?

Comment: node env for example, though I like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). You can use an .env file with your credentials then. @alextix

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.